# Why does the question list show "0" for this already-answered question?

Tags: bug, answers, migration

An answer has been posted to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150781/did-the-us-government-classify-the-whaley-house-as-haunted-and-if-so-why).

The [Travel list of questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com), however, shows "0" in the "Answers" box. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is this because it's been migrated? Some other reason?

Comment: It has a deleted answer.  It's not visible to low rep users.

Comment: Needs a non-deleted answer with positive upvotes for it to appear in the list as answered.

Comment: The answer shown on Travel has no indication it's been deleted. And I found the question in its new location on Skeptics...and the Skeptics question list does, indeed, show "1" in the "answers" space. Doesn't that indicate the "0" in the Travel questions list results from no answer being posed _while the question was active on Travel_ ?

Comment: don't think so (although happy to be proven wrong) - it was answered 8 hours ago, but only migrated from travel 3 hours ago.

Comment: That does disprove my hypothesis. <shrug>

Answer (score 1):

Moving a question to an other stack does reset the counter for answers to 0. This is because existing answers get deleted on the old stack (but appear again on the new stack.)

Samples:
[is it possible to go with the babies (Italian passport holders) but leave them in Brazil for a month or two?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150367/is-it-possible-to-go-with-the-babies-italian-passport-holders-but-leave-them-i?noredirect=1).

[Can I work in Switzerland with a French Carte de sejour? I am an Indian national married to a French citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/149936/can-i-work-in-switzerland-with-a-french-carte-de-sejour-i-am-an-indian-national?noredirect=1)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the answer number reset that occurs when a question is moved; that explains the zero. But there's this: you said "...existing questions get deleted on the old stack..." The question I asked about was migrated from Travel to another site (Skeptics), yet not deleted on the old stack — it still appears on the Travel list of questions. The two questions you cite in your answer also continue to appear on the Travel list of questions. What do you mean by "existing questions get deleted on the old stack..." ?

Comment: When I checked all three questions each had one answer with the message 'delete x hours/days ago' with no indication who deleted them.

Comment: Sorry, should have been 'answers' get deleted. Edited now.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for the clarity about this.